# sed editor: How to remove all fields except ones that I want in text file

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains multiple lines with fields (from FIX protocol) like this:

```
35=V|311=123|515=ABC|825=BBB|9803=AKEFP Oct 12|55=1
35=V|311=456|515=CDE|825=CCC|9803=BUF Nov|55=33|66=8
```

I need to remove all fields except 311 and 9803, so for the above lines I want to receive:

```
311=123|9803=AKEFP Oct 12
311=456|9803=BUF Nov
```

How is it possible to do this with sed editor (or with another application)?

Comment: `cut -d\| -f2,5` would work for your given sample data...

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your data is really consistent and always has the same number of columns in the same order you can do it easily with `awk`

```
awk -F'|' '{print $2 "|" $5}' file.dat
```

This command sets the record separator to `|` and then prints the second and fifth record for each line. If the structure of your data file is not as consistent and you actually have to pattern match, you can use the following more complicated `awk` expression

```
awk -F'|' '/311|9803/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i~/311|9803/)printf "%s|", $i} printf "\n"}' file.dat
```

This will output

```
311=123|9803=AKEFP Oct 12|
311=456|9803=BUF Nov|
```

Note the trailing `|` which if that is really a problem you can edit this after the fact

Comment: You can reuse the `FS` like this: `awk -F\| '{print $2 FS $5}' file`

Comment: Your second attempt will fail if data equals to `311`, example `9803=BUF Nov|55=311|66=8`.  You should use some like this: `if($i~/\<(311|9803)=/)`

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that this is a too complicated issue and I will better write a short C++ program to do this.